# Make a threaded function waits an operation forced in the main thread inside it to finish - Kivy

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I have a big function in kivy that takes time, i wanted to tread it but this function have some operations that are opengl related, so i made a 3 functions of those operations and used the @mainthread decorator on them to force them to run in the main thread, it works good but there is a big problem, those function that used the @mainthread decorator waits for the next frame to run, so the thread run all it's code before those operations even run, the thread code relies on those opegl operations to execute, so errors occur, I tried a lot but i can't force it to wait the the opengl operations to finish.

Here's a simplified structure for the function:-

```
def func1():
    code
    code

    @mainthread
    def func2()
        code
    
    func2()

    code
    code

threading.Thread(target=func1).start()
```

here's the original function if it's important to look at:-

```
            def load_data():
                global original_len

                if not exists(self.file_path + ".pycsv"):

                    for row in csv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8'):

                        if self.row_num == 0:
                            original_len = len(row)
                            if args[0]:

                                if int(args[0][-1]) > len(row):
                                    args[0] = ""
                                    self.row_len = len(row)

                                else:
                                    self.row_len = len(args[0])

                            else:
                                self.row_len = len(row)

                            self.title_grid.cols = self.row_len
                            self.cells_grid.cols = self.row_len
                            
                            @mainthread
                            def add_no():
                                
                                self.title_grid2.add_widget(JoButtonLabel(text="No.", width=50, height=35,
                                                                          size_hint=[None, None]))
                            
                            add_no()
                        while len(row) != original_len:
                            row.append("")

                        if args[0]:
                            extra_data = row[:]

                            if self.row_num == 0:
                                self.title_row = deepcopy(extra_data)

                            for i in sorted(args[0], reverse=True, key=lambda s: int(s)):
                                extra_data.pop(int(i) - 1)

                            if self.row_num == 0:
                                self.title_grid2.children[0].extra = extra_data

                            row = [row[int(i) - 1] for i in args[0]]

                            if self.row_num == 0:
                                self.displayed_titles = row

                        else:
                            extra_data = []


                        if self.row_num != 0:
                            #Adding row numbers
                            self.data2.append({'text': str(self.row_num), 'width': 50, 'height': 35, 'font_name': 'MEIRYO.TTC', 'font_size': '15sp', 'size_hint': [None, None], 'background_color': self.theme[0]})

                            if args[0]:
                                self.data2[-1]['extra'] = extra_data

                        for i in enumerate(row):

                            if self.row_num == 0:
                                #Adding titles
                                
                                @mainthread
                                def add_titles():
                                    if sizes:
    
                                        try:
                                            self.title_grid.add_widget(JoTitle(text=i[1], size=sizes[(i[0] * -1) - 1]))
    
                                        except IndexError:
                                            self.title_grid.add_widget(JoTitle(text=i[1], size=[int(args[3]), 35]))
                                    else:
                                        self.title_grid.add_widget(JoTitle(text=i[1], size=[int(args[3]), 35]))
                                
                                add_titles()
                                
                            else:
                                #Adding cells
                                size = self.title_grid.children[(i[0] * -1) - 1].size[:]

                                self.data.append({'dyn_size': size, 'multiline': False, 'text': i[1], 'font_name': 'MEIRYO.TTC', 'size_hint': [None, None], 'index': len(self.data)})

                                if args[0]:
                                    self.data[-1]['extra_index'] = int(args[0][i[0]])-1

                        self.row_num += 1

                    self.find_col = self.row_len - 1
                    self.title_grid.children[(self.find_col * -1) - 1].children[2].background_color = [0, 0, 0, 1]

                else:
                    with open(self.file_path + ".pycsv", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as df:
                        lines = []
                        for i in df:
                            lines.append(i)

                        self.title_row = ast.literal_eval(lines[0])
                        dc = ast.literal_eval(lines[1])
                        self.title_grid2.add_widget(JoButtonLabel(text="No.", width=50, height=35,
                                                                  size_hint=[None, None]))

                        for t in enumerate(dc):
                            self.title_grid.add_widget(JoTitle(text=t[1], size=ast.literal_eval(lines[2])[(t[0] * 1) - 1]))

                        self.title_grid2.children[0].extra = ast.literal_eval(lines[3])
                        self.args = ast.literal_eval(lines[4])

                        temp = lines[5].split(",")
                        self.row_num = int(temp[0])
                        self.row_len = int(temp[1])
                        self.find_col = int(temp[2].strip("\n"))

                        self.title_grid.cols = self.row_len
                        self.cells_grid.cols = self.row_len
                        self.title_grid.children[self.find_col].children[2].background_color = [0, 0, 0, 1]
                        self.duplicates_list = ast.literal_eval(lines[6])
                        self.marked_rows = ast.literal_eval(lines[7])
                        self.data2 = ast.literal_eval(lines[8])
                        self.data = ast.literal_eval(lines[9])
                        
                @mainthread
                def add_data_recycler():
                    self.scroll.data = self.data
                    self.scroll2.data = self.data2
                
                add_data_recycler()

threading.Thread(target=load_data).start()
```

Comment: You can use [Lock](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#lock-objects) objects to force threads to wait.

Comment: Locking doesn't work, it's the thread that needs to wait for an function in the main thread to finish, locking doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
@mainthread
def add_no():
    self.title_grid2.add_widget(JoButtonLabel(text="No.", width=50, height=35,size_hint=[None, None]))
    lock.release()
lock.acquire()
add_no()
if lock.acquire():
    lock.release()
```

Comment: This time i got no errors, but the app just stopped, goes to "Not responding" state

Comment: What's the meaning of this if condition you used? i can't get it, we acquire the lock than the function should release it right? what that if condition did here?

Comment: The `if lock.acquire()` makes the thread wait for the `add_no()` method to release the lock. Once the thread has acquired the lock, it immediately releases it to avoid deadlock. Add some print statements to see where your code has stopped (or perhaps use the debugger).

Comment: Ok, i will do it, but btw i just tried something and is's that i omited the use of the @mainthread, i once heared that opengl will bug if i run it outside the main thread, but it worked perfectly, without any problems, is this opengl thing is real?

Comment: Don't know about opengl, but you may encounter problems if you modify the kivy GUI outside the main thread.